# Disable today date in Datetime

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    elem = document.getElementById("date")
    var iso = new Date().toISOString();
    var minDate = iso.substring(0,iso.length-1);
    elem.value = minDate
    elem.min = minDate
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="datetime-local" id="date" />
</form>
```

I am using [an HTML5 datetime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) `<input>` as a datepicker on my webpage. How can I disable today's date in the control so that the user can only select future dates?

Comment: Can you put code that you have try so for.Which calendar property you have using?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    elem = document.getElementById("date")
    var iso = new Date().toISOString();
    var minDate = iso.substring(0,iso.length-1);
    elem.value = minDate
    elem.min = minDate
});

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this code to add one day in current day.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
 elem = document.getElementById("date")
  var d=new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);

  var iso = d.toISOString();
  var minDate = iso.substring(0,iso.length-1);
  elem.value = minDate
  elem.min = minDate });
</script>
```

Comment: Nothings disable and it just enable past date to be click

Comment: Can you edit his question and add html part you have using.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>With `var minDate = iso.substring(0,iso.length-1);`, you're going to end up with something like `2019-03-28T12:30:21.000`. An ISO Date String looks like `2019-03-28T12:30:21.000Z`, so all you're doing is stripping off the `Z`.</strike>

Change it to `.substring(0, 10)`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elem = $('#date');
  var iso = new Date().toISOString();
  var minDate = iso.substring(0, 10);
  elem.value = minDate;
  elem.min = minDate;
});
```

Note that this will let you select dates in the future, *including today*. For tomorrow onwards, swap `var iso = new Date().toISOString();` with `var iso = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400000);`.

`86400000` is `1000ms (1 second) * 60 * 60 * 24`.

1 second * 60 = 1 minute
1 minute * 60 = 1 hour
1 hour * 24 = 1 day

For datetime-local....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ONE_DAY = 86400000;
  var elem = document.getElementById('date');
  var minDate = new Date();
  minDate.setHours(0);
  minDate.setMinutes(0);
  var iso = new Date(minDate.valueOf() + ONE_DAY).toISOString();
  var minDateString = iso.substring(0, iso.length - 8);
  elem.value = minDateString;
  elem.min = minDateString;
});
```

Note that it is still possible to enter invalid values, as additional validation is dependent on the browser implementation of the field. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Validation for more information.

Comment: This code is not working as per requirement, Kindly check and update.